# It is necessary to create an inner class, using it as a instance variable of the outer class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

My question is if it's right to create an inner class only because I need to access from this class to one of the outer instance variable. But the real problem is "It's right to use this inner class also as an instance variable of the same outer class?".

In my specific case, I have the outer class called `Exam` and should have a result associated but the result (it will be a `String` or a `Double`) depends on the `ExamType` (that's is a Exam instance variable).

So I am not sure if the best practise is:

- to create an isolated `Result` class receiving as constructor input the `ExamType`
- to create a inner `Result` class that could easily access to the `Exam` instance variable (in particular `ExamType` variable) and instantiate it as a instance variable of the `Exam` class.

Comment: You should go through [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) and [Inner Classes Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

Comment: Option 1 is probably cleaner and will be easier to test in isolation.

Comment: An isolated Result class with ExamType in constructor will probably be a good way. Its clean.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for option 1: passing the `ExamType` in the constructor of `Result`.

The reason is mainly testability: with `Result` only depending on objects explicitly passed to it, it's easy to test its functionality in isolation.

The other possible reason is serialization: if you just want to serialize a `Result` object, having it as an inner class of `Exam` will force `Exam` to be serialized with it. More often than not this isn't what you want.

*Whether `Result` is a top-level class or a `static nested` class is up to you, that decision is a matter of readability. If your `Result` class is relatively simple and `Exam` isn't very complicated either, use a static nested class, otherwise use a separate top-level class.*

Comment: Thanks for the clean answers!
I have only a point to clarify, if I decide to set `Result` as a `private static nested` class and I create a `Result` Object this object can't access to `Exam` class instance variables so I have to leave the constructor because this class will behave as a top-level class, it's right?

Comment: Yes. A static nested class behaves almost exactly the same as a top-level class. (The only difference is in access to `private` fields or methods.)